# How to match two text lines exactly in python?

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I am working on a log file filter. I want to check whether several input text lines are existing in the log file.Followings are some of my text lines.

```
Instrument ID = 121212121
Book Definition ID = NORMAL
Trader ID = TRQ01
Order Type = 2
Source ID = <Unset>
Instrument Index = <Unset>
Value = <Unset>
Side = 2
Qualifier = <Unset>
Order Qty = <Unset>
Visible Size = <Unset>
TIF = 0
```

Following is a part of my log file.

```
~|A|SMsg:Sequenced Message{
~|A|{
~|A|    Routing Seq = 28545
~|A|    Origin = 1
~|A|    Transaction ID = 28483
~|A|    Sequenced Message = ~|A|        SMsgLite:NEW NEW ORDER
~|A|    {
~|A|            Instrument ID = 121212121
~|A|            Book Definition ID = NORMAL
~|A|            Trader ID = TRQ01
~|A|            Order Type = 2
~|A|            Source ID = <Unset>
~|A|            Instrument Index = <Unset>
~|A|            Value = <Unset>
~|A|            Side = 2
~|A|            Qualifier = <Unset>
~|A|            Order Qty = <Unset>
~|A|            Visible Size = <Unset>
~|A|            TIF = 0
~|A|            Order Sub Type = 3
~|A|            Inactive Time = <Unset>
~|A|            Expiration Date = <Unset>
~|A|            Contingent Value = <Unset>
~|A|            Owner ID = TRQ01
~|A|            Client Order ID = 380-6XAC3Vw6W
~|A|            Transact Time = <Unset>
~|A|            Symbol = <Unset>
~|A|            IsSurveillance = 1
~|A|            Reason = sd
~|A|            Gateway Rejection = <Unset>
~|A|            Order Reject Code = <Unset>
```

I have two main problems

1. I want to ignore `"~|A| "` character set when I am matching. That means I want to start matching at the 5th character position of the line.
2. I wan to find the complete matches for above text lines.
   Here is my lookup function

   ## Return the boolean True if there a match

   ```
   def BooleanLookup(self,infile,regex,start,end):
       self.infile = infile
       self.regex = regex
       self.start = start
       self.end = end

       for line in itertools.islice(infile,start,end):
           line = line.rstrip()
           if re.match(regex, line):                
               return True
               break
           else:
               return False
   ```

But it returns true even the times that part of string is matches. How do I implement a method to get a completely match.

Comment: Why use RegEx at all?  `line[16:] == 'Instrument ID = 121212121'` will work fine

Comment: It's not working to me. Can you tell me the code which you use to read the 'Instrument ID = 121212121'

Comment: Where are you getting your "text lines" from?

Comment: by reading a file. This is my parameter getting function jsfiddle.net/afafe9rq any wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

re.match(regex, line) will return an object if line partially contains regex from left. If you want to use your code, change

```
if re.match(regex, line):
```

to

```
if re.match(regex, line) and re.match(regex,line).span()[1] = len(line):
```

Comment: I think I have a problem with getting text lines too. I get the text lines by reading the text files. that process 'Instrument ID = 121212121' this kind of variables included a whitespaces too. The are caused to a matching faliure.

Comment: There is probably a newline character at the end of the string. use `strip()` to get rid of it.

Comment: This is my parameter getting function                    https://jsfiddle.net/afafe9rq/ any wrong with it?